# Specifying dependency from another dependency explicitly maven

Tags: java, maven

I am writing a library that has following dependencies:

```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
  <version>[3.1.0,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
  <version>[3.1.0,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```

Now the problem is - some of the users of this library also use it with `dropwizard-core` and in which case my library provides some additional features for the dropwizard framework and hence `dropwizard-core` is an optional dependency.

Problem is - when user imports `dropwizard-core` - it automatically will include other dependencies I specified above (such as `metrics-core`) and in that case - the version imported via `dropwizard-core` may conflict with version explicitly specified.  How do I solve this?

Bunch of users of this library will use it - without `dropwizard-core` and hence I don't want these users to import `dropwizard-core` (and hence atomic dependencies).

Comment: The user who imported that (I assume you mean using as a dependencies) can override your decisions. Furthermore i recommend you never to use version ranges....If you have optional dependencies than define them as optional...

Comment: That is okay, I have dropped the versions ranges and made specific versions. But dependencies are still weird overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You should probably pick one based on usage patterns. E.g., is the extra dependency most of the time excluded or included?

**1. Exclude explicitly (include by default)**

Keep it as it is, then ask users to exclude the extras if necessary:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>something-important</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>something-extra</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**2. Exclude by default (include explicitly)**

Modify your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>something-extra</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>something-extra</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Use optional when it's implied that your library can work just fine without it, just some parts might not work. Use provided when it's implied that your library needs it, but it's up to the user to figure out where to get it (or which implementation).

See documentation for both: 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: For your scenario I would recommend using `<optional>true</optional>`.

Comment: For now, I have went with the option of using optional for `something-extra` dependency. The only catch was - I had to figure out exact version of `jetty-servlet` etc that is compatible with `something-extra` version.